# How do I implement Calendar Events from WKWebView into my iPhone?

Tags: swift, calendar, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I have a UIViewController in which a WKWebView is implemented. My problem is: I would like, because on the Websites URL is a button with a calendar event, import this into my app. In other words, if you push the pushed button a query appears in which app you want to import the calendar event. You select a calendar app of your choice and this calendar event is then imported into the calendar

Is there a way to do this with Swift?